# Accuracy of double equality boolean when cast from Integer/int/Long/long

Tags: java, double, equals, equality, primitive

What is the accuracy of the equality test if the below datatypes are cast to `Double` (the `.equals()` test) or to `double` (the `==` test)?

- `Long`
- `long`
- `Integer`
- `int`

If the equality test is only accurate within a range of possible `Long`, `long`, `Integer` or `int` values, what is the precise range over which this accuracy holds?

For example;

```
Long longTest = Long.MAX_VALUE;
Long longTest2 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
double doubleTest = (double) longTest;
double doubleTest2 = (double) longTest2;
if(doubleTest == doubleTest2) //Is this accurate? 
     return true;
```

Comment: When asking "what is the accuracy of the equality test..." I believe that you are confusing accuracy with precision.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it as follows:

Both double and long occupy 64 bits storage. For float and int, it is 32.

Because there are some bits spent on the exponent, you will always be in danger of loosing precision when casting a long to a double or an int to a float.

The only save thing is int -> double.

Anyway, as to your example: the double cannot hold the Long.MAX_VALUE with absolute precision, for the reason stated above. It will be an approximation. However, the approxiamtion should be the same every time, hence your example should return true.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would have been possible for the creators of Java to have defined `==` overloads for all combinations of numeric types so that only things with the same numeric value would compare equal [implying, for example, that there would be no `float` value which compares equal to 16777217], or to have forbidden the use of `==` on any combination of types where that operator wouldn't behave as an equivalence relation, they did neither of those those things.  Instead, they decided that it should be possible to compare operands with any combination of primitive types, whether or not that is meaningful, and such comparisons should use the same implicit conversions as exist in any other context (a decision I really dislike, btw).

Consequently, a comparison between e.g. a `long` and a `float` will be performed by performing an approximate conversion to `float` and comparing that, without regard for whether any precision was lost in the conversion.  A comparison between `float` and `double` will be done by performing an exact conversion to `double` and comparing that.  This leads to 16777216.0f == 16777217, and 16777217 == 16777217.0, but 167772176.0f != 16777217.0.  There are times when one may want to know whether the `float` is the *best* `float` representation of the other value, and times one may want to know whether it's an exact representation, but the type ranking in Java is inconsistent with regard to which question the `==` operator answers.

Answer (score 0):

Several cases...

If both types are wrappers, equals is always precise - but do mind that equals is type sensitive (e.g. Integer.equals(Long) always yields false, regardless of value). Otherwise...

If one type is a wrapper and the other is primitive, the wrapper will be unboxed and the comparison is done using == semantics the same as both types were primitives from the start.

Equality for primitives (==) is precise for any integer type (byte, short, int, long) - the smaller type will be cast to the larger type, then compared. For char, its cast to the larger type but *unsigned*.

Equality with one operand a floating point type (float, double) the other type is cast to the floating point type and there is *potentially* precision lost in that case. Float can represent any integer value that has <= 24 significant bits precisely, double has 53 bits of relevant precision (its determined by the number of mantissa bits in the type, see IEEE754 for dirty details).

So basically, float == (int) N is only precise when (approx.) abs(N) <= (1 << 23), and double = (long) N when abs(N) <= (1 << 52). If there are more significant bits in the integer type, the lowermost bits are *lost* when the type is cast to float/resp. double. Since double has more mantissa bits than int can have significant bits, comparisions between double and int are precise in that regard.